# Sphinx directives to another page

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have 2 pages included in the toc.

On page_1 I have following

```
The link :py:class:`testtest`
```

On page_2 I have

```
The link :py:class:`testtest`
.. autoclass:: testtest
```

On page_2 the link is working because the class has been auto documented using autoclass.

Why does the same link on page_1 not work? How can I make it work without including the autoclass directive on page_1?

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

`page_1` doesn't know where to find `testtest` - `page_2` finds it because it implicitly looks in the node's "scope" (so to speak) when it doesn't directly find it. Doing:

```
:py:class:`module.testtest`
```

in `page_1` should work (if your paths are set up right), you can also do:

```
:py:class:`~module.testtest`
```

to only have `testtest` as the link text. To avoid having to do the module prefix, you can use a `.. currentmodule:: modulename` directive, but only one of those can apply at a time, so if you're refrencing things in multiple modules, doesn't really save typing.

http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#directive-py:currentmodule
http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#xref-syntax
http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects